# Visualize sparsity pattern with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a huge sparse matrix of about 10.000 x 10.000 entries with 60.000 non-zero entries. I'd like to visualize the pattern, that means zero entries are ignored and non-zero entries are marked with a small circle, maybe colored by its value.

Just printing a pixel for each entry is not enough, as the image would be scaled down and the result barely visible.

Something like Matlab's [spy](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) function would be great.

Comment: spy in matlab and `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @percusse Definitely not. I'd like to load the data from an external file and make all the processing / visalization with TikZ. That can be scripted, is better in a version control etc.

Comment: That big matrix is just impossible with TeX.

Comment: Most of the entries will be zero. Hmm, but still. You might be right. Out of curiosity: What about the example from the Matlab documentation with 60x60 entries?

Comment: I would generate a file with 60000 lines with `x,y,value` entries (with a script or whatever) and then try to plot a scatter graphic. Disclaimer: I do not know if 60k line is manageable... never tried.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305250/creating-scatter-plot-from-data-file-with-missing-values-sparse-matrix?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something to try on. It uses `tikz` and `pgfplotstable` to fetch the data. It iterates through the table, tough you have to inform the table size beforehand in `\nrows` and `\ncols`. I have no idea about performance for big data sets, likely it will be bad (as expected).

The relationship between value and Format/Color is yours to make. Though as percusse said, 10 000x 10 000 Matrix is just too big...

## MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data-table.dat}
1   2   3   4   5
6   6   8   5   4
1   0   8   5   1
1   2   0   4   5
6   6   8   5   4
1   0   8   5   1
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread{data-table.dat}\mytable
\def\nrows{5}
\def\ncols{4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nrows}{
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\ncols}{
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of\mytable
    \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=0\relax\else
    \node[circle, minimum size=.5pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=red!\pgfplotsretval!purple, opacity=0.\pgfplotsretval] at (\j pt,-\i pt) {};
    \fi
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Making a 60x60 Matrix with "random" integers from 0 to 50 and using the above MWE I got this:

[image]